# Call controller of a project from a diff project using jQuery Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can we call a controller of one project from another project using Jquery Ajax, MVC4?

If we can, how to do that?

I have tried the below but it is not working:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/test/Testing",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        //We need to send some in future...                       
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $("div[data-stage = \"stagerWidget\"]").html(data.results[0]);
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to add the reference from your project with controller to main project in solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by specifying type of request (get or post).